# Add timestamps to chat "Kick" notifications

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, kick-mute

I'd like to request a small addition to the notifications room owners get on chat, when a user is kicked.

I usually leave my PC on, overnight. Since I'm a RO in a couple of rooms, it's not that uncommon for someone to get kicked, while I'm counting sheep.
As it's important to recognize repeat offenders, I usually try to have a look at what kind of action resulted in the kick. More often than not, this means searching pages of the transcript for messages sent by that user.

A **timestamp** or a **link** to the user's last message would be of great help in checking out the user's actions.

Another alternative would be a RO-only log of room owner related actions. Kicks could be shown, but also entries for moved messages.

Comment: +1 to both suggestions, I often wake up to those notifications as well and would like to see the context

Comment: +1 I would agree that this is a useful suggestion

Comment: Does that notification mention *how long* the user is kicked?

Comment: It does, @Deduplicator.

Answer (score 28):

Yes please, I'd like to add another suggestion - the timestamp should be a link to the room last message (not the user's since it might have been moved or removed at that point) at the time the kick was performed.

That way owners will be able to get useful context for the kick.

Comment: A log of RO actions, similar to what we have on our profile on `?tab=activity` would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that more context on a kick would be nice, especially when we're trying to better self-moderate our room, and a RO needs context on who was kicked and why.

Seeing a list of

```
[user1] was kicked by [RO1] for X minutes
[user1] was kicked by [RO2] for X minutes
...
```

Can help find the context by asking the relative timestamp or what happened, etc, but having the context immediately available would help ROs keep up on who is causing trouble.